# In elasticsearch I'm trying to delete all items that exactly match and it doesn't work

Tags: elasticsearch

I have FIELDNAME mapped to "not_analyzed"

`curl -XDELETE "http://127.0.0.1:9200/data/_query" -d'
{
    "query": [
      { "match": { "FIELDNAME": "Exact Match Text" }}]
}'`

WHat am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [match query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) should not be an array, but rather an object:

```
curl -XDELETE "http://127.0.0.1:9200/data/_query -d \
'{
  "query" : {
    "match" : {
      "FIELDNAME" : "Exact Match Text"
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Works! Thanks.  What if I wanted to match 2 fields.  like match firstname = bob lastname = smith?

Comment: You would want to use the [multi match query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html).

Comment: I asked the question in another question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726514/in-elasticsearch-im-trying-to-multi-search-multiple-fields-with-multiple-values  I had looked at the multi match.

Comment: I misread your original question; my brain ignored the last sentence. Since they have different values, then `multi_match` is not the best option. I answered it in the linked question, but `bool` queries are the better approach here.