# In elasticsearch I'm trying to multi search multiple fields with multiple values is it possible?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have firstname and lastname mapped to "not_analyzed"

```
curl -XDELETE "http://127.0.0.1:9200/data/_query" -d'
{
  "multi_match" : {
    "query":    "Will"
    "fields": [ "firstname" ] 
  },{
    "query":    "Smith"
    "fields": [ "lastname" ] 
  }
}'
```

It doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?   Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing piece to a lot of Elasticsearch's documentation is that the queries are themselves within a `query` (or `filter`) and that is meant to be implied.

Now, since they are different fields *with different values*, you can go in a few different directions, but I think that the best option would be to use a [`bool query`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html):

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        { "term" : { "firstname" : "Will" } },
        { "term" : { "lastname" : "Smith" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

That should match:

```
{
  "firstname" : "Will",
  "lastname" : "Smith"
}
```

If you had a structure like

```
{
  "name" : {
    "first" : "Will",
    "last" : "Smith"
  }
}
```

then you would just change `"firstname"` and `"lastname"` to `"name.first"` and `"name.last"` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to delete all documents matching your query or search for them? If you want to search for them. Try:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/data/_search" -d'{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "firstname": "Will"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "lastname": "Smith"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}'
```